# Why use Java's AsynchronousFileChannel?

Tags: java, nio

I can understand why network apps would use multiplexing (to not create too many threads), and why programs would use async calls for pipelining (more efficient). But I don't understand the efficiency purpose of AsynchronousFileChannel.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9):

It's a channel that you can use to read files asynchronously, i.e. the I/O operations are done on a separate thread, so that the thread you're calling it from can do other things while the I/O operations are happening.

For example: The `read()` methods of the class return a `Future` object to get the result of reading data from the file. So, what you can do is call `read()`, which will return immediately with a `Future` object. In the background, another thread will read the actual data from the file. Your own thread can continue doing things, and when it needs the read data, you call `get()` on the `Future` object. That will then return the data (if the background thread hasn't completed reading the data, it will make your thread block until the data is ready). The advantage of this is that your thread doesn't have to wait the whole length of the read operation; it can do some other things until it really needs the data.

See [the documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousFileChannel.html).

Note that `AsynchronousFileChannel` will be a new class in Java SE 7, which is not released yet.

Comment: Thanks, but I was wondering more about the efficiency reasons -- I can't see why performing the I/O in another thread helps. One thread always has to block for the I/O, and there is no reported resource re-use, hardware feature utilization, or any other performance-enhancing behaviors.

Comment: The advantage of this is that you *don't* need two threads. If you are writing a large blob of data, at the low-level, the disk controller does the job of writing data to disk before signalling an interrupt which goes up the stack to invoke your completion handler.

Your thread needn't block during this process and can do other stuff. You use one less thread, the thread scheduler manages one less thread, you don't need to use java notify. Basically, you utilize less resources to do the same thing.

Comment: The operating system can also optimize the order in which asynchronous IO operations are executed. For example, if you have a large number of reads of a variety of regions in a file that are performed asynchronously, the OS can group them together into sequential reads, without having to worry about executing all the operations in the precise order given.

Comment: @Ross, what prevents the OS to "group" the parallel requests from different threads? So, grouping does not explain the 2x performance gain.

Comment: @Jesper, Not using threads waiting for I/O completion is definitely saves some resource but I do not believe that one extra thread that does nothing (it also waits in parallel) eats a half of the performance that Ross Judson reports.

Comment: The reason for the performance gain is that you pipeline the request (from a single thread) because you dont have to wait for the first request to finish before issuing another request. Thus teh disk controller will spend less time waiting on an empty request queue and more time executing the request.

Answer (score 3):

I've just come across another, somewhat unexpected reason for using AsynchronousFileChannel. When performing random record-oriented writes across large files (exceeding physical memory so caching isn't helping everything) on NTFS, I find that AsynchronousFileChannel performs over twice as many operations, in single-threaded mode, versus a normal FileChannel.

My best guess is that because the asynchronous io boils down to overlapped IO in Windows 7, the NTFS file system driver is able to update its own internal structures faster when it doesn't have to create a sync point after every call.

I micro-benchmarked against RandomAccessFile to see how it would perform (results are very close to FileChannel, and still half of the performance of AsynchronousFileChannel.

Not sure what happens with multi-threaded writes. This is on Java 7, on an SSD (the SSD is an order of magnitude faster than magnetic, and another order of magnitude faster on smaller files that fit in memory).

Will be interesting to see if the same ratios hold on Linux.

Comment: Indeed, as long as your files are short to fit OS cache, I/O completes immediately regardless of your I/O is synchronous or not. I just would add that you'll get 2x speedup max when your I/O and computation are of comparable length. If computation is only tiny fraction of I/O time or I/O is negligibly shorter than computation then overlapping them does not makes sense either.

Answer (score 3):

The main reason I can think of to use asynchronous IO is to better utilize the processor.  Imagine you have some application which does some sort of processing on a file.  And also let's assume you can process the data contained in the file in chunks.  If you don't make use of asynchronous IO then your application will probably behave something like this:

1. Read a block of data.  No processor utilization at this point as you're blocked waiting for the data to be read.
2. process the data you just read.  At this point your application will start consuming CPU cycles as it processed the data.
3. If more data to read, goto #1.

The processor utilization will go up and then to zero and then up and then to zero, ... .  Ideally you want to not be idle if you want your application to be efficient and process the data as fast as possible.  A better approach would be:

1. Issue async read
2. When read completes issue next async read and then process data

The first step is the bootstrapping.  You have no data yet so you have to issue a read.  From then on, when you get notified a read has completed you issue another async read and then process the data.  The benefit here is that by the time you finish processing the chunk of data the next read has probably finished, so you always have data available to process and thus you're more efficiently using the processor.  If your processing finishes before the read has finished you might need to issue multiple asynchronous reads so that you have more data to process.

Nick

Answer (score 2):

Here's something no one has mentioned:

A plain `FileChannel` implements [`InterruptibleChannel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/InterruptibleChannel.html) so it, as well as anything that uses it such as the `OutputStream` returned by [`Files.newOutputStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newOutputStream-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-), has the unfortunate<sup>[1][2]</sup> behaviour that performing any blocking operation on it (e.g. `read()` and `write()`) in a thread in [interrupted state](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt--) will cause the `Channel` itself to close with [`java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/ClosedByInterruptException.html).

If this is a problem, using `AsynchronousFileChannel` instead is a possible alternative.

- <sup>[1]</sup> http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6608965
- <sup>[2]</sup> https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4469683